# NumberPicker exclude one value

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I have a following question - I've created NumberPicker and also I've set minValue and maxValue for it. Is there any way to exclude one certain value from list of values?

Here's my code for NumberPicker:

```
public class YearSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NumberPicker yearPicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_year_selection);
    yearPicker = findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    yearPicker.setMinValue(2006);
    yearPicker.setMaxValue(2018);
 }
}
```

For example, I want to exclude 2011 from this list, is there any way to do that, using standart NumberPicker?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(String[] displayedValues);
```

to display custom values for the number picker. Create a String array with the values that you want to display and use the `setDisplayedValues` method to display them

Comment: So, is it the only way? And I can't just exclude one number, if I've set minValue and maxValue, can I?

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't just exclude a value

Comment: Ah, okay. I knew, that I can do that by an array, but I wanted to search, is there any other solutions. Thank you.